# Powerbuilder : How to Get the RowNumber of specific data on datawindow

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow, powerbuilder.net

Good Day!,
Can anyone here give me a hint or idea on how to get the rownumber of specific value in datawindow.

i have 2 objects, treeview and datawindow with same Value. Treeview data are sorted  but in datawindow is not. when i click an item in Treeview it will show the rownumber  in datawindow correspond to value clicked in treeview. How can i do that?

Best regards,
Newnbie

P.S Sorry for my English

Comment: I've already solve this with some clever solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use dw.Find(*). Code example:

```
long ll_row
string ls_keyValue, ls_dwSearch

// Read value from TreeView
ls_keyValue = '...'

// "MyKey" :: Column in DataWindow containing the key read from tree view
ls_dwSearch = "MyKey = '" + ls_keyValue + "'"
ll_row = dw_data.Find(ls_dwSearch, 1, dw_data.RowCount( ))

if ll_row > 0 then
   // Key value found => Make row current and visible
   dw_data.ScrollToRow(ll_row)
end if
```

Comment: If you want to make the row highlighted, you can use the SelectRow method as well.